# What's the difference between push and add-to-list?

Tags: elisp, list

I've found that different packages in their installation instructions use either push or add-to-list (For example adding a directory to load-path) and I was wondering what the difference is and what the use case for each would be.

Comment: I was struggling to convert code using `add-to-list` to code using `cl-pushnew`, and I found this blog post to be quite enlightling: https://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/emacs-lisp-lexical-binding-gotchas-and-related-best-practices/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What #zck mentions is one difference. But if that were the only difference then you could ask about `cl-pushnew` and `add-to-list`.

Another important difference: `add-to-list` is a function, which means that it evaluates all of its arguments, in particular, the first one. `push` is a macro (as is `cl-pushnew`) - it does not evaluate its second argument; instead, it interprets it as a generalized place.

For example, if the second argument is a symbol then it is regarded as a variable, and the value of the first argument is consed onto the value of that symbol as a variable, and the variable is set to that new cons.

As the doc string of `add-to-list` says:

```
This is handy to add some elements to configuration variables,
but please do not abuse it in Elisp code, where you are usually
better off using `push' or `cl-pushnew'.
```

Comment: Also according to the byte-compiler: `add-to-list can't use lexical var ...; use push or cl-pushnew`

Comment: `(push (5 6) my-list)` still gives me an error -- `5` is not a function. How is this different than `add-to-list`'s behavior?

Comment: @markasoftware: What are you trying to do? If you want to push the list `(5 6)` to the place (value of variable) `my-list` then you need to create the list `(5 6)`. One way to do that is to use `'(5 6)`; another is to use `(list 5 6)`. `push` evaluates the argument.

Comment: @Drew you say now that it evaluates the argument, but your answer literally states "it does not evaluate its first argument", which is the source of my confusion.

Comment: @markasoftware: I'm sorry; I had a typo - I wrote "first argument" where I should have written "second argument". Corrected now - thanks. The second arg to `push` is a place, such as a variable. The first arg is evaluated, consed onto the value of that variable, and the variable is set to that new cons. `add-to-list` evaluates its first arg to produce the variable whose value gets updated. `push` does not evaluate its second arg, which is the variable to update. The arg order is reversed between the two.

Comment: @Drew Got it! For my own reference, are there any "places" that `push` accepts but, when quoted, wouldn't work in `add-to-list`?

Comment: @markasoftware: Not sure what you mean, but `push` accepts a *generalized variable* (the "place"). `add-to-list` accepts only an ordinary variable (a symbol - the result of evaluating its first arg). See the Elisp manual, node [Generalized Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generalized-Variables.html).

Comment: @markasoftware concretely: Try this `(let ((my-alist '((foo 3 4 5) (bar 7 8 9))))
  (push 111 (alist-get 'foo my-alist))
  my-alist)` That doesn't work with `add-to-list `.

Answer (score 21):

Another difference:

`push` adds *element* to the beginning of *list*.

`add-to-list` allows you to add *element* to either the beginning or end of *list*.

```
(setq testasdf nil)

(push 'a testasdf)

testasdf
(a)

(add-to-list 'testasdf 'b)

testasdf
(b a)

;; add element to the end
(add-to-list 'testasdf "hello" t)

testasdf
(b a "hello")
```

Answer (score 18):

From the [Emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html#List-Variables), or `C-h f push`:

> Macro: push element listname
>
> This macro creates a new list whose car is element and whose cdr is the list specified by listname, and saves that list in listname.

From the same page, or `C-h f add-to-list`:

> Function: add-to-list symbol element &optional append compare-fn
>
> This function sets the variable symbol by consing element onto the old value, if element is not already a member of that value.

So `add-to-list` only pushes if the element isn't already there.

Comment: `cl-pushnew` behaves like `add-to-list`.