# Symbol's value as variable is void: tramp-remote-path

Tags: tramp, customize

I'm trying to configure a remote path when using tramp. I have added `(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/root/.cargo/bin")` to my `init.el`

I get the following error:
`Symbol's value as variable is void: tramp-remote-path`

The tramp docs suggest this is the correct pattern:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-programs.html

`tramp-version` is `2.4.3.27.1`

Emacs version is: `GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin20.3.0, NS appkit-2022.30 Version 11.2.1 (Build 20D74)) of 2021-03-07`

I can do `apropos-user-option` `tramp-remote-path` and find it in the configuration options.

Comment: You have a typo in your config, use something like `(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/root/.cargo/bin)`. If the typo is in the post, then you can modify `tramp-remote-path` nested in `(with-eval-after-load "tramp" (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/root/.cargo/bin"))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between push and add-to-list?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/whats-the-difference-between-push-and-add-to-list)

Comment: You can also search for tag `[quote]`, to find various questions that amount to the same thing: not quoting an arg value that needs to be quoted. In this case, `C-h f add-to-list` is your friend, telling you that it's a function (functions eval their args), and it needs a symbol that's a variable (with a list value) as its first arg.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong type argument: symbolp, 10](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57892/wrong-type-argument-symbolp-10)

Comment: Same issue here. Swarnendu's sugestion of wrapping it with-eval-after-load resolved the issue for me.